# How do you return a file from an API response flask_restful?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I Have two API's one is basically for generating PDF's basing on the data sent.

This first API endpoint below

```
http://localhost:5000/api/sendReceiptData
```

Returns a PDF file as an attachment.

The second API will consume the first API and should return a PDF as an attachment in the response. I have tried it out but I get this error `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

How can I therefore return a file response from the first API within this second API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `send_file` method to return pdf file

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, make_response, send_file
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
PDF_FOLDER = '/path/to/pdf/folder'  # Replace with the path to your PDF folder

@app.route("/pdf/<string:filename>", methods=['GET'])
def return_pdf(filename):
    try:
        filename = secure_filename(filename)  # Sanitize the filename
        file_path = os.path.join(PDF_FOLDER, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            return send_file(file_path, as_attachment=True)
        else:
            return make_response(f"File '{filename}' not found.", 404)
    except Exception as e:
        return make_response(f"Error: {str(e)}", 500
```

Comment: The [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.send_file) pretty clearly point out to "Never pass file paths provided by a user" which is exactly what you are doing here. You should use [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) here instead.